# Unable to call class methods in two different classes swift

Tags: swift

i am unable to call class instance for more than one class in swift .

i have three view controllers .

1)ViewController
2)RegistrationVC
3)WebServiceInterface

WebServiceInterface having a method

```
func postRequest(postString: String, postUrl:String, currentVC:ViewController){
    // ... some code
}
```

i am able call this method from ViewController but not from RegistrationVC

from ViewController it is fine

```
var webServiceInterface = WebServiceInterface()
webServiceInterface.delegate = self
webServiceInterface.postRequest(str, postUrl: url, currentVC: self)
```

but from RegistrationVC it showing:

> Cannot invoke 'postRequest' with an argument list of type '(String, postUrl: String, currentVC: RegistrationVC)'

```
var webServiceInterface = WebServiceInterface()
webServiceInterface.delegate = self
webServiceInterface.postRequest("asd", postUrl: "asd", currentVC: self)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that your `RegistrationVC` class is not a subclass of your `ViewController` class.

To resolve this, you should either change your method to expect a `UIViewController` (notice the `UI`) or to change `RegistrationVC` to be a subclass of `ViewController`, which ever makes most sense (probably the former).

---

We can make more sense of this by reading the error message:

> Cannot invoke 'postRequest' with an argument list of type '(String, postUrl: String, currentVC: RegistrationVC)'

This error tells us a few things.

First of all, the compiler indeed is finding our method named `postRequest(:postUrl:currentVC:)`, but the problem lies in the types of arguments we're passing.

The compiler thinks we're trying to pass a `String`, `String`, and a `RegistrationVC`.  So how does this differ from what is actually defined for the method?

Well, we got the strings right, so it must be the last parameter that is wrong.  The compiler expects a `ViewController` object for the third parameter, but we're trying to send a `RegistrationVC` (which is probably a subclass of `UIViewController`, which is different from `ViewController` (which is one of your own subclasses of `UIViewController` and in need of a better name).

So the best solution most likely is (depending on your implementation of `postRequest(:postUrl:currentVC:)` and what you're doing with `currentVC:` within the method) to simply change the type of that third parameter:

```
postRequest(postString: String, postUrl: String, currentVC: UIViewController) {
    // implementation code
}
```

Comment: Here no dependencies are there for those 3 classes , i am having 3 different classes and i want to access one class method from other two classes

Comment: You can.  But you have to pass the correct parameters.  If you expect to pass instances of those two other classes as parameters (which is your actual problem here), then the parameter for which you're passing them in must be a parameter that can accept both classes.  Either a common superclass, a protocol they both conform to, or a generic.